# Monitor stay on after computer go to sleep

Tags: multiple-monitors, sleep

When my dual-screen computer goes to sleep, one of the monitor will stay on with bright color screen, and I am not able to turn it off. The same problem was on my old Windows 7 computer, when I switch to a new Windows 10 computer, the same problem appears again.

I think it should be some games my son installed on the computer, but I am not able to identify what program, I killed all the process, but same thing happen.

Comment: The monitor that has problem is a Dell, but I am sure it is not the monitor, I had changed different monitors on different brands several times.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of monitors are you using?  My secondary monitor is a 32" LG that requires software to use the multiple split screen/PIP options.  That software was causing problems with a number of other programs on my system, so I removed it (I didn't need all those display options anyway), and everything worked fine again.  If one or both of your monitors has similar software, that could be causing the problem.

Otherwise, look in Control Panel,System.Power Options and check "change when display turns off."  It should be next to "change when your computer goes to sleep.